# How to change a sine function?

Tags: trigonometry

I use sine functions to control cyclic animations I create with code. For example, I can use something like `a * sin(millis() * f * 2 * pi)`, and assign that value to some property of a geometry, making it cycle from -a to a.

I’d like to have some kind of “dumping” applied to it, so that the curve goes “faster”/“slower” to 1.  I played a bit with combining sine with other functions but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you sketch a graph of what you want?  (Perhaps a graph of sine with time as the horizontal axis, with a second curve that is closer to/further from 1 in the way you are thinking would work.)

Comment: Is dumping, with that spelling, definitely the description you intended?

Comment: What controls the speed is $f$. You need to change that. What do you mean "the curve goes faster/slower to 1"? Why 1?